# Using jQuery to find an id within a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists

I have a list of attributes the first of which contains the active class.

```
<ul class="parcel-tabs panel-header">
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="fee-summary-tab" href="#feeSummary" class="active">
            <span class="tab-label">Fee Summary</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="relationships-tab" href="#relationships">
            <span class="tab-label">Parcel Relationships</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="accounts-tab" href="#accounts">
            <span class="tab-label">Accounts</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use jQuery .find() to select the 'fee-summary-tab' id which uses the active class however I keep resulting in undefined.

```
.on('click', '#relationships-tab', function (event) {
    var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li a').find('.active');
    alert(activeTab.data('id'));
});
```

Comment: You could only select the element with active class and console log the id `console.log(document.querySelector('a.active').id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, `.find` looks for descendants of an element, so since you've already got to an `a` with your selector, it won't find that element even if it does have the `active` class. Changing your selector to `ul.parcel-tabs li a.active` means you don't need to do a `find`. Secondly, you get `id` from `.attr`, not `.data`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#relationships-tab', function(event) {
  var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li a.active');
  alert(activeTab.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parcel-tabs panel-header">
  <li class="tab-list">
    <a id="fee-summary-tab" href="#feeSummary" class="active">
      <span class="tab-label">Fee Summary</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-list">
    <a id="relationships-tab" href="#relationships">
      <span class="tab-label">Parcel Relationships</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-list">
    <a id="accounts-tab" href="#accounts">
      <span class="tab-label">Accounts</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.find`, as the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/find/) say, searches in the *descendants* of the selected elements. Whereas in your HTML, your `active` class is attached to the `a` elements themselves.

So you should change

```
var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li a').find('.active');
```

to either

```
var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li a.active');
```

or perhaps

```
var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li').find('.active');
```

according to which you prefer, or which works better with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var activeTab = $('ul.parcel-tabs li').find('a.active')[0];
console.log(activeTab.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parcel-tabs panel-header">
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="fee-summary-tab" href="#feeSummary" class="active">
            <span class="tab-label">Fee Summary</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="relationships-tab" href="#relationships">
            <span class="tab-label">Parcel Relationships</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-list">
        <a id="accounts-tab" href="#accounts">
            <span class="tab-label">Accounts</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```